# How to change the maths symbols in preamble?

Tags: symbols, preamble

I have already finished writing my work and now I decided to change notation. How can I do it in preamble? More precisely I use `$\mathcal{R}([a,b])$` in all my work and I would prefer to get `$\mathcal{R}[a,b]$`.

Comment: Had you used something like `\newcommand\myexp[3]{\mathcal{#1}([#2,#3])}`, the only thing to do would be to delete the parentheses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You *could* redefine `\mathcal` to do the replacement on the fly but it would be fragile and make your tex fragments hard to use in any other context. Better to use a regular expression replace and just edit the source.

For example starting from a file reg.tex

```
$\mathcal{R}([a,b])$
```

then a sed command line such as

```
$ sed -e 's/\\mathcal{R}(\([^()]*\))/\\mathcal{R}\1/g' reg.tex
```

would output

```
$\mathcal{R}[a,b]$
```

with the round brackets gone.

`sed` is standard in some operating systems but similar regular expression edits could be made in any reasonable text editor.

Answer (score 4):

Define a command:

```
\newcommand{\myR}[2]{\mathcal{R}[#1,#2]}
```

and change all the instances of `$\mathcal{R}([a,b])$` into `$\myR{a}{b}$`. It won't help you much this time, because you'll still have to manually (or semi-automatically, with regexp) the source. But when you change your mind and decide that `$\mathcal{R}([a,b])$` was better after all, you'll have it easier.

I realize this is probably not the answer you were expecting, but I guess other solutions are going to be a headache (now and later).